# MS Edge Driver as separate conf file in wdio

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, webdriver-io, selenium-edgedriver

Can someone, please, assist, in following:

Created separate conf files for **Chrome** & **Firefox** on **webdriver.io** (latest version 7.19.3), but could not acchive to create (also separate) config file for **Microsoft Edge** driver, on Widows 10 machine. At the main conf file (**wdio.conf.js**) are just regular settings without any browser settings, and would like to leave it that way.

What I did:

```
exports.config = merge(wdioConf.config, {
capabilities: [
{
  maxInstances: 1,
  browserName: 'MicrosoftEdge',
  osPlatform: 'Windows',
  osVersion: '10',
  acceptInsecureCerts: true,
},
],
baseUrl: 'https://some.site.for.testing,
waitforTimeout: 10000,
connectionRetryCount: 3,
services: ['selenium-standalone'],
seleniumArgs: {
  javaArgs: [
      '-Dwebdriver.edge.driver=path.join(__dirname, "./node_modules/selenium-standalone/.selenium/edgedriver/17134/MicrosoftEdgeDriver.exe")'
   ]
 }
});
```

Or other config, which also tried:

```
exports.config = merge(wdioConf.config, {
capabilities: [
 {
  maxInstances: 1,
  browserName: 'msedge',
  acceptInsecureCerts: true,
 },
],
 baseUrl: 'https://some.site.for.testing',
 waitforTimeout: 10000,
 connectionRetryCount: 3,
 services: [['selenium-standalone', { drivers: { msedge: 'latest' } }]],
});
```

But, without any success. When run

```
npx wdio run config/wdio.edge.conf.js
```

*Either get that "missing configuration" or runner get stuck*

When run tests either with **FF** or **Chrome**, it runs smoothly.

```
npx wdio run config/wdio.chrome.conf.js
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If can be useful to anyone, only solution which acchieved, is:

Create copy of **wdio.main.conf** and inside browser capabillities add **edge** setup (used solution provided in :https://dev.to/tswiftma/webdriverio-edge-driver-options-5038).

Finally, rename **main.conf** into, i.e **wdio.msedge.conf**.

```
NOTE: If just add Edge config into main.conf (and not create a copy of main.conf), tests will only run in Edge. In FF & Chrome will not,
```

Main cofig file **wdio.main.conf** remains as it were before changes